# How to search array of objects contains an item in another array?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, vmware, powercli

I have two arrays.

An array of objects containing Virtual Machine Information called `$vms` one of the attributes called `Name`. Here's the type:

```
PowerCLI > $vms.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

I have another array imported from a CSV file called `$importVMs` where one of the fields is also called `Name`.

I want to do some work if `$importVMs.Name` does not exist in `$vms` (i.e. it doesn't match any `$vms.Name`). I'm wondering if I can do this with pipelining, or do I have to iterate through both arrays?

can I do something like `if (! $vms | ? {$_.Name -neq $importVms.Name) { # work }`

Can't seem to get it to work. Do I need to `foreach` the `$importVms` in that `if` condition?

**EDIT**

My complete script so far:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server vCenter -Protocol https -Force | out-null
$importVms = Import-Csv vCenterVMs.csv
$VMHost = "esxi"
$currentVms = Get-VM
Write-Host "Current registered VMs" -ForeGroundColor Cyan
$currentVMs

Write-Host "Saved VMs to import" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
$importVms

$registered = @()
Write-Host "Importing VMs..." -ForeGroundColor White
#$importVms | ?{$_.Name -notcontains $currentVms}

foreach ($vm in $importVms) {
    if (! $currentVms.Name -contains $vm) {
        Write-Host "Importing $($vm.Name)"
        # put in a try block here
        $registeredVM = New-VM -VMFilePath $vm.VmPathName -VMHost $VMHost -Location $vm.Location
        $registeredList += $registeredVM.Name
    }
}

$registeredList
Disconnect-VIServer -Server * -Confirm:$false
```

vCenterVMs.csv looks like

```
"Name","VmPathName","Location"
"test","[RAID5] test/test.vmx","testfolder"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use to -notin or -notcontains operator for that.

```
$importvms | ?{$_.Name -notin $vms.name} | %{ Do Stuff }
```

Alias `?` used for `Where`, and `%` used for `ForEach`.

Ok, it that doesn't work we can try building a regex match string out of your array of current VM names, and matching each imported VM against that to see if it already exists. Try this script:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server vCenter -Protocol https -Force | out-null
$importVms = Import-Csv vCenterVMs.csv
$VMHost = "esxi"
$currentVms = Get-VM
Write-Host "Current registered VMs" -ForeGroundColor Cyan
$currentVMs

Write-Host "Saved VMs to import" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
$importVms

$registered = @()
Write-Host "Importing VMs..." -ForeGroundColor White
#$importVms | ?{$_.Name -notcontains $currentVms}

$VMNameFilter = "($(($currentVms|%{[RegEx]::Escape($_.Name)}) -join "|"))"

foreach ($vm in $importVms) {
    if (! $vm.Name -match $VMNameFilter) {
        Write-Host "Importing $($vm.Name)"
        # put in a try block here
        $registeredVM = New-VM -VMFilePath $vm.VmPathName -VMHost $VMHost -Location $vm.Location
        $registeredList += $registeredVM.Name
    }
}

$registeredList
Disconnect-VIServer -Server * -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Hi, I believe -notin is Powershell3+?  I'm using Powershell 2.

Comment: Also, using `-notcontains` instead always results in a positive match when it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks, I had to change the `if` statement to `if ($vm.Name -notmatch $VMNameFilter)` to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, which would be better used in a script:

```
Foreach ($ImportVm in $ImportVms.name) { 
if ($vms.name -notcontains $ImportVm) {
DO STUFF }
}
```

The Foreach is looping through the VM names in the array $ImportVMs, putting each individual VM name from $ImportVMs in the variable $ImportVM at each loop.

Then , the "if" statement checks if the array of names in $vms doesn't contain the $ImportVM currently in the loop.
If this "if" statement evaluates to true, then the script will do whatever is inside the { }.
I just put { DO STUFF } here, because you didn't mention what you want to do with these VMs.

Comment: Second Lal, this could use some explanation. It's currently in the automated Low Quality Posts queue. I'm recommending it not be deleted, but you need to flesh it out a bit.

Comment: I added some explanations to my answer.

Comment: I added some explanations to my answer.
There is not that much to explain, this is just a basic Foreach loop with an "If" statement inside of it.
For the basics on Foreach in Powershell , I would recommend this article :
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/28/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach.aspx

Comment: If I use `Foreach ($ImportVm in $ImportVms.name)` then I don't get access to other properties of `$ImportVm` such as `$ImportVm.VmPathName` in the execute script block. If I use `Foreach ($ImportVm in $ImportVms)` then the `if` condition always matches (when it shouldn't).